# Who is Stronger: Ventus, Aqua or Terra?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

In Kingdom Hearts: Birth By Sleep, I want to know who is stronger. Is it Ventus, Aqua or Terra? In addition, what are the advantages of choosing the strongest one?

Comment: Could technically be a duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50186/is-there-any-advantages-to-playing-birth-by-sleep-in-any-particular-order

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terra, Aqua and Ventus each fall into three pretty stereotypical RPG character skill sets. They are:

- **Terra** : The Warrior
- **Aqua** : The Mage
- **Ventus** : The Thief

So, as you can imagine, Terra is the strongest. If you want to think of it in terms of Kingdom Hearts:

- **Terra** : Chose the shield, gave up the wand
- **Aqua** : Chose the wand, gave up the... sword? (she's fairly balanced for attack and defense actually)
- **Ventus** : Chose the sword, gave up the shield

As far as advantages, [there are really no story advantages to picking one over the other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50186/is-there-any-advantages-to-playing-birth-by-sleep-in-any-particular-order), but there could be others, depending on your experience.

Most people find it easier in the beginning to play through **Terra (the warrior) first**. You have a chance to get used to the controls, and get familiar with everything and you'll end up being able to take a lot of hits while you're learning.

Personally, I would go with **Aqua (the mage) second**. She's fairly balanced on offense and defense and there are a number of AOE attacks that allow you to blow through people. It's a little harder to level her, but once you do (and spend some time on the command board if you're struggling) you'll be able to blow through enemies.

And **lastly, Ventus (the thief)**. He can take a bit of getting used to since he usually can take fewer hits, but he is quick, and has some decent magic. His attacks don't do quite what Terra's will do, but you'll be able to do some quick combos and get things moving.

From person experience playing the game, I think that the order story-wise makes most sense as Terra, Ventus, and then Aqua, but my recommendation in terms of ease is the above.

Answer (score -1):

Aqua is the strongest of the trio. Her dodge gives you immunity for about 1.5 seconds more than Ventus's one, she is the only character to have a 360^ defence, incredibly strong magic commands that can easily wipe out enemies in one or few shots ( thundaga shot, triple firaga/blizzaga etc ). She is Not that slow while moving. The only things she lacks are defence ( that is However Not as bad as Ventus, and attack speed ( that she really does Not need since she should be used as a pure mage ). She may be the weakest at early levels, but in the end she is the strongest in both gameplay and plot.

Answer (score -1):

Terra is strongest with defence and ground attacks, taking a lot of hits and doing the most damage on the ground.

Answer (score -1):

Ventus is the best. His stats are usually in between Aqua's and Terra's apart from being quicker than both of them.

He only has decent attack but he is still a better damage dealer than Terra because his combos finish much quicker and he usually doesn't get hit when he's in the middle of them, unlike Terra.

Aqua is just plain better a magic but her mediocre speed and low attack makes Ventus a bit better.

Answer (score -4):

Terra is strongest and has good keyblades near end game. He also a warrior type character

Comment: Why is Terra strongest?  Back up your claim with evidence.  Having good keyblades doesn't really tell you much at all.